# Telerik RadGrid Bound to EntityFramework Paging does not function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, telerik, radgridview

Problem: "Paging" does not work on my Telerik RadView nor does "Page Size".
The black works, but what's circled in red doesn't: 
[image]

```
  <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
             <AjaxSettings>
                 <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="TGrid">
                   <UpdatedControls>
                       <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="TGrid">         </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                   </UpdatedControls>
               </telerik:AjaxSetting>
           </AjaxSettings>
          </telerik:RadAjaxManager>





 <telerik:RadGrid ID="TGrid" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch" ClientSettings-Virtualization-LoadingPanelID="RALoading" CssClass="RadGrid_Rounded" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanged="TGrid_PageIndexChanged" OnPageSizeChanged="TGrid_PageSizeChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="TGrid_DataBound" >
    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced" ></PagerStyle>
       <MasterTableView Width="100%" DataKeyNames="SubmissionID">
           <Columns>
        //columns here
           </Columns>
           </MasterTableView>
         </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Here's the datasource it's bound to:

```
 protected void LoadGrid()
    {
         TGrid.DataSource = dbContext.Mains.OrderByDescending(x => x.VoteCount).ToList();
           TGrid.DataBind();
       }
```

The paging function:

```
  protected void TGrid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, GridPageChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e != null)
        {
            TGrid.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            TGrid.TabIndex = e.Item.TabIndex;
            TGrid.DataSource = ViewState["Grid"];
            TGrid.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

The page-size changing function:

```
  protected void TGrid_PageSizeChanged(object sender, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
             {
             TGrid.PageSize = e.NewPageSize;
             TGrid.DataSource = ViewState["Grid"];
             TGrid.DataBind();
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.ToList()` you are fetching all of the data on every call of LoadGrid().

An alternative, which will automatically fetch single pages of data from the database, is to use a `<asp:EntityDataSource />` and set this as the `DataSourceID` of the RadGrid.

You can then remove the LoadGrid() function.

If you find that EntityDataSource isn't sufficient for your needs then I suggest using advanced RadGrid binding see http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-advanced-data-binding.html